# Laravel's Passport: How to have an authenticatable model

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

The problem with the [Laravel's Passport tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport) is that it assumes the reader will use the pre-installed `User` model, that is very different from the simple model we could create with `php artisan make:model MyModel`.

Here is the code of the pre-installed `User` model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

And here is the code of a model you could create with `php artisan make:model MyModel`:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class MyModel extends Model
{

}
```

But what if I want my own custom authenticatable models, say `Customer`, what should I do to follow the Passport tutorial? Is there an Artisan command that implements all the interfaces, add all the traits and extend the corresponding class for us?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think in config/auth.php change the value of the providers with the new model will help.

Comment: @sachinkumar Yes, but that doesn't change the content of the custom authenticatable model.